# Center 1 of 2 inner divs in outer div

Tags: html, css, centering

I have an outer div element with two inner div elements in it. I want to center one of two inner div elements, the other inner div element should stay on the left.

Here is the code with an example outer and inner div that shows that it is in fact not centered in the inner and outer div below it.

You can also find a codepen here: http://codepen.io/TheCodingWombat/pen/YyzmNE

code.html

```
<div class="outer-example">
  <div class="inner-example">
    <h3>The Center</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner1">
    <h4>Topic</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="inner2">
    <h3>Board Title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

code.css

```
.outer-example {
  text-align: center;
}

.outer {
  text-align: center;
}

.outer > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner1 {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [my modified version](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoaXmv) of your code pen. Basically, I changed it so that instead of floating the inner element, I changed its position to absolute relative to the parent container that contains both it and the desired-to-be-centered div.

```
.outer {
  ...
  position: relative;
}

.inner1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

When you `float` something, it's mostly removed and becomes non-blocking, but `float`ed things will still effect `inline` and `inline-block` elements in terms of positioning.